# Laravel 7 Auth password sent in plain text

Tags: laravel, laravel-authentication

I have default auth implemented in Laravel 7 and works like a charm.
However, I have a very peculiar requirement wherein, the password shouldn't even travel in plain text although SSL is implemented on network.
One way would be to handle it via javascript on login page wherein I encrypt the value of password and send the same to server and then decrypt the same in php before handing it to laravel attemptLogin method.
However, I am not so sure about this approach.
Any help would be awesome.

Solution:

On client side, used crypt.js/aes.min.js and encrypted the password using a key and iv.

In login controller, overrode credentials method and decrypted using openssl_decrypt before passing on to hash check.

Comment: Please share your code what you have tried

Comment: I solved it using the method in the edited question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it as below:

On client side, used crypt.js/aes.min.js and encrypted the password using a key and iv.

In login controller, overrode credentials method and decrypted using openssl_decrypt before passing on to hash check.

Answer (score 1):

This is already discussed on [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/110418):

> It is standard practice to send "plaintext" passwords over HTTPS. The
> passwords are ultimately not plaintext, since the client-server
> communication is encrypted as per TLS.

And [this one](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/8600):

> If you hash on the client side, the hashed password becomes the actual
> password (with the hashing algorithm being nothing more than a means
> to convert a user-held mnemonic to the actual password).
>
> This means that you will be storing the full "plain-text" password
> (the hash) in the database, and you will have lost all benefit of
> hashing in the first place.

You may also read [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/7058) for more security options.

Comment: Yes, I understand this. But the client is adamant to even secure client side. I found a solution later using crypto js.

Comment: @Ankur You may post an answer to your own question, if you have found a solution for others with the same problem in the future.